# Import Javadoc with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to include java docs or source when I import a library with gradle.

Furthermore, I obviously don't want that source/javadoc going out with my program, bloating it, so can I automatically have it not go out with a compile?

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I couldn't find the right keywords. Any help would be great!

Comment: What exactly you mean under "include java docs"? Include by which program or system? What exactly you mean under "going out with my program"? Do you generate javadoc and want to disable such generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadoc/source attachment for Gradle libraries isn't implemented yet. You can track it at bugs https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59220, which is for source attachments, and the nearest bug I can find that's specific to Javadoc is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59115.

When that support is finally added, you won't have to worry about sources or docs being bundled into your APK -- the build system will know to not do that.